# Spring Security LDAP vs Basic Authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, ldap

I've burned a few days trying to get something that should be simple to work.  I have an application (web app) that works with Spring Security 3.0.5 and I'm having a hell of a time trying to switch out my `authentication-manager` for something that supports LDAP.

I'm using JSF and it seems like most of the tutorials out there are geared towards `jsp`

I'm by no means a spring expert and I've hobbled something together off some tutorials I found scattered around the web.

#### Servlet-context.xml

I'm not 100% sure exactly what this file does?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd">

<!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

<!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
<beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
    <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
    <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</beans:bean>

</beans:beans>
```

#### Security.xml

This file appears to define the security configuration and such as well as what parts of the web app are locked down.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd">

<http use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/ff/**"         access="isAuthenticated()" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="permitAll()" />

    <!-- Custom login page -->
    <form-login login-page="/login.jsf" authentication-failure-url="/login-fail.jsf"/>

    <!-- Custom logout page -->
    <logout logout-success-url="/login.jsf"  invalidate-session="true"/>

</http>

<!-- Use inline authentication provider. -->
<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder hash="md5"/>
        <user-service>
            <user name="admin" password="21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN,ROLE_USER" />
            <user name="raj" password="0b438dd454bc6a17de239ebf0a46b91b" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

#### Web.xml

It appears this file tells the web-app which additional spring fillets parse

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee     http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
        /WEB-INF/spring/security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>




<!-- Enable Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<!-- Allow login pages with JSF which redirects to security check, therefore we have to add the forward entry here -->
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
    <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/spring/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>


<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>
</web-app>
```

And lastly I have a bean (i think) that handles the security stuff

#### SecurityWrapper.java

```
import java.util.Collection;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

/**
* Code from: http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security
*/
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SecurityWrapper {

public String getUser() {
    Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (!(authentication instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken)) {
        String currentUserName = authentication.getName();
        return currentUserName;
    }
    return "NO USER DETECTED";
}

/*This is a example for to obtain the rol name for example for generate automatic menu    */
public String getRole() {

    /*This is a example for to obtain the rol name for example for generate automatic menu    */
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    String namePrincipalRol = null;
    if (auth instanceof AnonymousAuthenticationToken) {

        namePrincipalRol = "ROLE_ANONYMOUS";
    } else {

        namePrincipalRol = auth.getAuthorities().iterator().next().getAuthority();
    }
    return namePrincipalRol;
}

private void getUserDetails() {
    UserDetails userDetails = (UserDetails) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().
            getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
    System.out.println(userDetails.getPassword());
    System.out.println(userDetails.getUsername());
    System.out.println(userDetails.isEnabled());
}

private boolean hasRole(String role) {
    Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = (Collection<GrantedAuthority>) SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getAuthorities();
    boolean hasRole = false;
    for (GrantedAuthority authority : authorities) {
        hasRole = authority.getAuthority().equals(role);
        if (hasRole) {
            break;
        }
    }
    return hasRole;
}

 public String logout(){
     getUserDetails();
    SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();

    return "loggedout";
}

}
```

### Questions

So here is where I'm running into issues.  1) This example code I put together (much came from: http://www.baeldung.com/get-user-in-spring-security) is running **Spring 3.0.5** which probably is very out of date, but I'm hoping that shouldn't matter.  I've gone various routes attempting to integrate and/or switch out my authentication provider for LDAP but I keep running into issues where my tutorials are of a different version and when I try to upgrade spring things go kaboom.  I'm assuming this should be a straight forward process but I would love some pointers as how to move forward.

There are various answers on stack for integrating Spring LDAP but they are all (mostly) related to `.jsp` and not`.xhtml` which may/may not matter - and I've run into much trouble trying to integrate the other ones.

*Should this be a straight forward process* or is it actually more involved than I realize?  And if/so is it as simple as just swapping out my `<authentication-manager>` or do i need to add special java code as well?

Comment: It should be as simple as switching the `AuthenticationManager`. It is just another store where the user information is coming from (like JDBC or In Memory or any Spring Social provider). Spring Security doesn't really care as long as it gets a populated `AuthenticationToken` (containing the `UserDetails` and `GrantedAuthorities`. Also looks like you are trying to work around spring security (at least with the logout function).

Answer (score 0):

So...assuming you have Spring security working and you wish to switch to LDAP

You need to have your authentication manager like so in your file Security.xml:

```
<sec:authentication-manager alias="webAuthenticationManager">
    <sec:authentication-provider ref="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" />
</sec:authentication-manager>
```

And the actual bean that does this:

```
<bean id="ldapActiveDirectoryAuthProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
    <constructor-arg value="yourcompany.com" />
    <constructor-arg value="ldap://yourserver.yourcompany.com:389 " />
    <property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="dataAutomationGrantedAuthoritiesMapper" />
    <property name="useAuthenticationRequestCredentials" value="true" />
</bean>
```

You also need to MAP the groups to Spring security roles:

```
<!-- Mapping of Groups (user is member of) to Application roles used by Spring security -->
 <bean id="dataAutomationGrantedAuthoritiesMapper" class="com.deltarail.view.web.login.DataAutomationGrantedAuthoritiesMapper">        
    <property name="groupToRoleMap">
        <util:map>
            <entry key="SystemAdministrators" value="ROLE_SYSADMIN" />
            <entry key="Maint"  value="ROLE_MAINT" />
            <entry key="General"value="ROLE_USER" />

        </util:map>
    </property>
</bean>
```